# VideoDisplay cannot load local flv files

Tags: apache-flex, flv, videodisplay

I have noticed that I have to put flv files in the same or sub-directories of the application file, for example `myproject/bin-debug/flvs/1.flv`, and use `videodisplay.source="flvs/1.flv"` to load.

If I put it in `myproject/flvs/1.flv`, I cannot load it in VideoDisplay, using `videodisplay.source="../flvs/1.flv"`. However the metadata (duration for example) is retrieved, but `play()` cannot start it.

Is there any solution to this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't put in your src folder, the files won't get exported.  Also they are not playing locally, but relatively from the browser sandbox (altho you can use flash player settings panel to get round this on your machine only)